# How do I pass a Float uniform to iOS Metal shader using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I want to pass a float to my metal shader. I cannot figure out how.

Here is my shader:

```
vertex float4 model_vertex(unsigned int iid[[instance_id]]
                           constant float angle) {
    float number = float(iid) / 64.0;
    return float4(number * sin(angle), number * cos(angle), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Now I want to pass it to the shader:

```
let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)
// ...
let angle: Float = 0.5
renderEncoder.setUniform1(angle) // What do I do here?
```

How do I pass the single float value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't seen setUniform* before. To pass uniforms to your vertex shader, use:

```
setVertexBuffer(buffer: MTLBuffer?, offset: Int, atIndex index: Int)
```

Where buffer would be an array with a single float, in your example.
To pass uniforms to a fragment shader use setFragmentBuffer.

Answer (score 13):

Also in 10.11+ and iOS 9+ you can use:

```
public func setVertexBytes(bytes: UnsafePointer<Void>, length: Int, atIndex index: Int)
```

Which is documented to be better than creating a MTLBuffer if you're only using the buffer once (and your data is less than 4K long).

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but OP's question has a vertex shader and `setFragmentBytes` sends data to fragment shaders, so if like OP you want to send data to a vertex shader use `setVertexBytes` instead.